# how to display distinct records, I want to check : if blueid is already present in the table show that data only once with particular date

Tags: android, mysql, sql

Table Name : Discovereddevices

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id        | int(100)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| blueid    | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| scannerid | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| datetime  | datetime     | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+--------------


+--------------+--------------------------+---------------------+
| blueid       | scannerid                | datetime            |
+--------------+--------------------------+---------------------+
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 10:40:20 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 10:45:16 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 10:50:14 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 10:55:15 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 11:05:21 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 11:10:15 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 11:15:22 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 11:20:17 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 11:25:18 |
| Galaxy Note3 | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 11:30:17 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 11:50:17 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 11:55:16 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:18:16 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:20:15 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:27:12 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:28:12 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:29:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:30:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:31:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:32:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:33:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:34:19 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:35:12 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:36:14 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:38:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:39:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:40:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:41:15 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:42:12 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:43:12 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:44:12 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:45:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:46:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:47:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:48:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:49:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:50:19 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:51:12 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:52:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:53:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:54:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:55:19 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:56:20 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:57:17 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:58:19 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 12:59:17 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:00:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:01:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:02:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:03:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:04:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:06:12 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:07:12 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:08:12 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:09:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:10:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:11:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:12:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:13:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:14:19 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:15:17 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:16:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:17:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:18:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:19:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:20:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:21:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:22:19 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:23:14 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:24:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:25:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:26:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:27:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:28:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:29:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:31:12 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:32:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:33:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:35:19 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:36:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:37:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:38:19 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:39:12 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:40:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:41:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:42:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:43:14 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:44:18 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:45:13 |
| yuviandroid  | CIS5040 Raspberry Device | 2017-04-07 13:47:17 |
+--------------+--------------------------+---------------------+
```

I used this query,

```
SELECT DISTINCT `blueid`,`scannerid`,`datetime`
FROM discovereddevices
WHERE date(datetime) = CURRENT_DATE.
```

Now, how can I get distinct values like yuviandroid only once with particular date.
Currently the data show distinct values taking time into consideration.
Can someine suggest on this.

Comment: Edit your question and provide the results you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will return the maximum datetime for each blueid:

```
select blueid, max(datetime) as max_dt
from discovereddevices
where date(datetime) = CURRENT_DATE
group by blueid, date(datetime)
```

And this query will return all other columns associated to the last datetime:

```
select d.*
from
  discovereddevices d inner join (
    select blueid, max(datetime) as max_dt
    from discovereddevices
    where date(datetime) = CURRENT_DATE
    group by blueid
  ) l on d.blueid = l.blueid and d.datetime = l.max_dt
```

Comment: I need distinct blueid's.Saying the data should be shown only once

Comment: @yuvasreekalaiselvan blueid will be distinct for each scannerid and for each date... if there are multiple blueid's for multiple dates which one you want to keep?

Comment: do you have any insights on this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289211/how-to-set-absent-to-those-fields-like-scannerid-datetime-and-status-when-ret

Answer (score 0):

Why include the date if you don't want it?

```
SELECT DISTINCT blueid, scannerid
FROM discovereddevices
WHERE date(datetime) = CURRENT_DATE;
```

Comment: I also need the date, only that. I wanted to check if blueid is already present in particular date it should be removed.

Comment: Why do you need the date?  The query specifies that the day is today, which is quite well-defined when the query is run.