# How to set "Absent" to those fields like scannerid, datetime and status When returns NULL after executing the JOIN query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Select distinct a.*,
  b.scannerid,
  date(b.datetime) as datetime,
  b.status from studentdetails a
LEFT OUTER JOIN discovereddevices b
  ON a.bluetoothid = b.blueid and date (b.datetime) = CURRENT_DATE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COALESCE

```
COALESCE(yourcolumnname,'Absent') as yourcolumnname
```

if the value is NULL for that column then the word Absent would appear in its place. Note you have to do that for each of the columns you want it done for.